Axios Ошибка при загрузке файла React Native
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: У меня выдает ошибку axios network error при попытке загрузить изображение на сервер. При этом, в веб-версии приложения все работает исправно. Так же все работает и с другими запросами на сервер (и в веб версии и в мобильной). Проблема только в загрузке изображения. Как это исправить?
  const pickFile = async () => {
    try {
      const { status } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (Platform.OS !== "web" && status !== "granted") {
        return alert("Нам нужно разрешение для доступа к вашей медиатеке!");
      }

      let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});

      if (!result.canceled) {
        const formData = new FormData();

        const fileData = {
          uri: result.assets[0].uri,
          name: result.assets[0].name,
          type: result.assets[0].mimeType || "application/octet-stream",
          size: result.assets[0].size,
        };

        const responseUri = await fetch(fileData.uri);
        const blob = await responseUri.blob();

        formData.append("file", blob, fileData.name);

        const response = await axios.post(
          `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/upload`,
          formData,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
          }
        );

        if (response.status === 200) {
          alert("Файл успешно загружен");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Ошибка при загрузке файла: ", error);
    }
  };

